# value do not pass in real device

Tags: objective-c, ios7

i am new in iOS.I am trying to send values on page to another using segue. but the problem is values proper pass in simulator but does not work in real device. i am using this code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"gologin1todatepicker"])
    {

        datepickerViewController *destViewController =segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.firstname1=self.firstname.text;
         destViewController.lastname1=self.lastname.text;
         destViewController.email1=self.email.text;
         destViewController.zip1=self.zipcode.text;
        destViewController.usertype1=self.usertype1.text;

    }
}
```

thnx in advnce..

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app on the device. Cleand and rebuild your project.

Comment: Then please provide more information. Did you debug it or log some statements? Can you say whether prepareForSegue: is beeing called or not? - Anyway, deleting the app and cleaning the project again would not do any harm.

Comment: i called in a button action. and i have debug it.

Comment: when i create ipa file the problem occur.

Comment: I don't understand. What problem occurs on creating the IPA file?

Comment: value properly pass in my simulator but when i create an ipa file and install it on a real device value do not pass..

Comment: What is it when you debug it on a real device? Is prepareForSegue beeing called?

Comment: yes it called because sometimes one value is pass and some time two sometime nothing. and right now i can't debug it on real device, some problem in my iphone. so only way to run on real device is create an ipa.

Comment: There must be something else. This piece of code looks ok to me.

Comment: i dont understand where is my mistake.